# Ignore C# compile warnings for specific sub-folders?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-construction

How can I selectively ignore compiler warnings at a folder level **without altering the source code files (*.cs)**? With the toy example below, I want to ignore CS0001 only for Lib1 (reviewed it to be ok) but nowhere else (since they could be unreviewed). Right now I can ignore compiler warnings only at the project level. Or I need to add `#pragma` to the source code which makes my source different from the library repository upstream which we cannot directly use (or link).

```
Project
 +-LibSrc
    +-Lib1 // Ignore CS0001 here
    +-Lib2 // Ignore CS0002 here
    +-Lib3
```

I'm hoping for some sort of project setting or some file places in the folder that signals this to the C# tools.

Comment: create 2 projects , one with all the libs that you want to ignore the warnings , and one with all the other code

Comment: Multiple projects generate multiple .dlls. A single DLL needs to be generated, that's why it's even in the folder structure as above to begin with.

Comment: you can use ILMerge to merge those 2 dll. Also both dll can have the same name space, so no problem here

Comment: That's not possible.  CS0001 is a compiler crash you can never ignore.  Not quoting real warning numbers doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the files to ignore, on File Properties, set Build Action to None. The compiler would ignore warnings from the files and build.

[image: File Properties]

Comment: Unfortunately that won't solve the problem as the files in question still need to be compiled.